# Как считывать сообщения от отправителя VK Api

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Имеется плагин на pocketmine(php) и каждую секунду обращается к методу https://api.vk.com/method/messages.get, но в response выходит только последнее сообщение от собеседника, а не отправителя.

```
  public function checkmsg(){
    $token = 'token';
    $jj = json_decode($this->curl("https://api.vk.com/method/messages.get?out=1&count=1&offset=0&v=5.65&access_token=$token"),true);
    $user = $jj['response']['items'][0]['user_id'];
    $text = $jj['response']['items'][0]['body'];
    $this->getServer()->getLogger()->info("$user : $text");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`messages.get` - Возвращает список **ВХОДЯЩИХ** личных сообщений текущего пользователя/сообщества.

`messages.getHistory` - Возвращает историю сообщений для указанного диалога.